# Windows 7 install, hanging black screen after reboot

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, installation

I've installed Windows 7 Home Premium 64, when it boots for the first time, after the "Starting Windows" load screen it takes me to a blank black screen with just a mouse pointer.

I've left it for over an hour, no changes.

I've cut the power and rebooted into safe mode. But it complains that I need to complete the install in normal mode, but that takes me to the blank screen.

I've found some suggested removing the USB devices, but that doesn't solve it for me.

I have had Windows installed on the exact same hardware before, from the same CD, so I'm stumped as to why it won't work.

Have tried fresh install process 5 times over, same results.

Comment: Have you changed any BIOS settings since your last successful install?

Comment: no bios settings have changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a very few articles on Black Screen and W7, seems like video is the main culprit.

.http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?mode=a&query=black+screen&spid=14019&catalog=LCID%3D1033&1033comm=1&ast=25&ast=28&res=20

Comment: I've checked through these, they don't appear to solve my issue. I have used the same hardware in the past for win7

Comment: Is this a desktop PC? if so try removing any non essential hardware prior to installing W7. Also try loading a 64bit driver for the graphics at the beginning of setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ran installation multiple times before unplugging HDMI cable. As soon as HDMI was unplugged the next stage in the setup was displayed.